# Probability - The birthday problem

Tags: probability, combinations, birthday

You go to a party which has 1000 guests (including you).

a) What is the probability that exactly one other guest has the same birthday as you?

b) What is the probability that at least two other guests have the same birthday as you?

---

My proposed solutions:

a) $(\frac{1}{365})\binom{999}1(\frac{364}{365})^{998} = 0.1771$

b) Probability of zero guests or one guest NOT having the same birthday.

Zero guests: $(\frac{364}{365})^{999} = 0.0645$

One guest: $0.1771$ (part a)

At least two guests: $1 - (0.1771 + 0.0645) = 0.7584$

Would this be the correct way to go about it?

Comment: Part a. looks good.  Don't understand the Zero Guest formula.  the probability that a given guest has a different birthday than yours is $\frac {364}{365}$ so the answer is $\left( \frac {364}{365} \right)^{999}$.  I don't understand the other factors you have.

Comment: Sorry I guess I was thinking too hard. So the zero guest would have an answer of 0.0645 for the final part b answer of 0.7584?

Comment: Should have said:  your overall methodology looks fine. It's just that one calculation I have a problem with.

Comment: Yes, that's the value I get.

Comment: if the birthdays were equally distributed you could use the pigeonhole principle was my first thought.

Answer (score 1):

With the standard birthday assumptions ($365$ days equally likely and each person's birthday independent of the others), your calculations look correct, as is your application of the binomial distribution

As a check in R

```
> dbinom(1, 999, 1/365)
[1] 0.1770821
> 
> 1 - pbinom(1, 999, 1/365)
[1] 0.7583954
> sum(dbinom(2:999, 999, 1/365))
[1] 0.7583954
```